# Updating a list within a tuple

Tags: python

I was just toying around in the interpreter and ran across something that I do not understand. When I create a tuple with a list as one the elements and then try to update that list, something strange happens. For example, when I run this:

```
tup = (1,2,3,[4,5])
tup[3] += [6]
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Which is exactly what I expected. However then when I reference the tuple again, I get:

```
>>> tup
(1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6])
```

So the list was in fact updated even though python threw an exception. How does that work? I can't imagine a scenario where I would actually want to do something like this, but I still would like to understand what is going on. Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is actually documented in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works).

**EDIT**: Here's a summary so that this is a more complete answer.

1. When we use `+=`, Python calls the `__iadd__` magic method on the item, then uses the return value in the subsequent item assignment.
2. For lists, `__iadd__` is equivalent to calling `extend` on the list and then returning the list.
3. Therefore, when we call `tup[3] += [6]`, it is equivalent to:

   ```
   result = tup[3].__iadd__([6])
   tup[3] = result
   ```
4. From #2, we can determine this is equivalent to:

   ```
   result = tup[3].extend([6])
   tup[3] = result
   ```
5. The first line succeeds in calling `extend` on the list, and since the list is mutable, it updates. However, the subsequent assignment fails because tuples are immutable, and throws the error.

Comment: I think the answer would benefit from the addition that it is because the extend isn't just `tup[3].__iadd__([6])`; it is `tup[3] = tup[3].__iadd__([6])`.  It's merely convenient that `list.__iadd__` returns the same object that it is mutating.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs! That's a big help.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch this in the docs. So to make sure I understand this right, basically in my example the list is updated because i am just doing tup[3].__iadd__([6]) and THEN python attempts (and fails at) the item assignment on the tuple? So I get the exception saying that it failed, but by that point we have already updated the list?

Comment: I updated my answer to try to summarize what the docs say - I hope that's ok! :)